# How to get image from django form ImageField input

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get an image from a input ImageFile to display in the template and also save that ImageFile to the models ImageField.

The code below spits out an error:

```
upload_img_temp.write(uploaded_image)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

**Form**

```
class UploadImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ['image']
```

**View**

```
def uploadImageView(request):
    form = UploadImageForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid:
            request.session['image'] = request.POST['image']
            return redirect('image:create')

def imageCreateView(request):
    uploaded_image = request.session.get('image')
    upload_img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile()
    upload_img_temp.write(uploaded_image)
    upload_img_temp.flush()

    form_create = ImageModelCreateForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,)

    if form_create.is_valid():
        instance = form_create.save(commit=False)
        instance.image = upload_img_temp
```

**Template**

```
<img class="image" src="{{ upload_img_temp }}">

  <form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit"></input>
    {{ form }}
  </form>
```

**Model**

```
def upload_location(instance, filename):
    filebase, extension = filename.split(".")
    return "%s/%s.%s" %('picx', uuid.uuid4(), extension)

class Image(models.Model):
    image           = models.ImageField(
                        upload_to=upload_location,
                        null=False,
                        blank=False,
                        )
```

Comment: can you post your model? and the form in html. What exactly are you doing here? Where is the rest of form validation? Maybe you should follow a super simple image upload tutorial and then make adjustments.

Answer (score 7):

So you have multiple problems.

1. `<form method="POST" action="" enctype='multipart/form-data' >`

You need to add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in the `form` otherwise no file will be accepted.

2. To display the Image you would need something like `<img class="image" src="{{Image.image.url}}">` Note that "Image" needs to be a valid arguments you defined in your views.py context part for this template. Its a reference to your model and the second "image" keyword refers to your model attribute "image". `.url` is required.
3. Change your views.py to something similar:

   ```
   def uploadG(request):
     form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
     if form.is_valid():
       print ("form was valid TEST") #controll your console and check if that statement appears when you click upload.
       instance = form.save(commit = False)
       ....
       instance.save()
       messages.success(request, 'You uploaded it')
   ```

Hope that helped. If not leave a comment

Answer (score 1):

There may be many possibilties for the error.
**Firstly** you need to make sure you specify upload_to attributes in quotes like
upload_to='images'

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(
               upload_to='images',
               null=False,
               blank=False,
              )
```

which will create a folder named images under the media folder and place image within this images folder.
**Second** you need to make sure that you add
enctype='multipart/form-data' inside  tag as

```
<img class="image" src="{{ upload_img_temp }}">

  <form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit"></input>
    {{ form }}
  </form>
```

**Third** instead of saving image to session you can simply save that image to your model class as model instance by saying

```
def uploadImageView(request):

    def uploadImageView(request):
        form = UploadImageForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid:
                form.save()
                context['form']=form
                return render(request, 'your_file_name.html', 
                {'context':context}
                )
```

and accessing that image instance in your template by setting img url as

```
<img url="{{form.image.url}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want image to be visible before user actually clicks "submit" button of your form?

For that you probably should look into handling ajax requests.

If you want to simply show image on the page, e.g. you want to upload it, save it to your database, then take it's url from database and put it in template, you should just call for "url" attribute of an image field.

For example:
You have **model** like:

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    image           = models.ImageField(
                        upload_to=upload_location,
                        null=False,
                        blank=False,
                        )
```

and you already saved image in the database.

To pass it from database to template you should do something like that in your **view**:

```
p_image = ProductImage.objects.get(id=3)
context['product_image'] = p_image
return render (request, 'template.html', context)
```

And then in your **template**:

```
<img class="product-image" src="{{ product_image.image.url }}"/>
```

Actually, using Ajax it will be pretty much the same thing, only you should send your form and update page via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

form: object = active_form(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=post)